# How to incorporate keyboard positions on character level embeddings?

Tags: neural-network, nlp, feature-engineering, word-embeddings

I am working with NLP and have **character level embeddings**.

I have embeddings learned from Wikipedia text.

Now, I want to learn embeddings from chat data (where misspellings and abbreviations are way more common). Usually, the character `n` doesn't follow from character `b`, however, during texting, this can be common because they are **close together on the keyboard**, and a misspelling occurs.

So, my questions is: **what are strategies to incorporate character keyboard position information to a traditional character level embedding?**

Note: it can be assumed that only QWERTY keyboards exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Character keyboard position information is an example of [noisy channel model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noisy_channel_model) information, an error that depends on how a word is transmitted. It is very common to add noisy channel model information to spell checkers, including spell checkers that use character-level embeddings.

Most character-level embedding models would automatically learn to model common transmission mistakes. Characters that are frequently confused in the dataset would be embedded closer to each other because they frequently co-occur. There would be minimal gain by explicitly adding channel information to a character-level embedding model during training.